# How to rotate a table in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a table with means for two different groups I'd like to rotate. The table is currently taking a lot of space vertically, and I need to rotate it to take space horizontally, like so:

```
        Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5 Var6 Var7 Var8 Var9 Var10 Var11 Var12
Group 1        -----numeric values-----
Group 2        -----numeric values-----
```

How would I go by in R to make this? I've tried transposing the table as dataframe, but this messes with the values in the table.

Comment: What do you mean by "messes with the values in the table"? Transposing the dataframe would be the standard way to go about this and should work with no issues for your example

Comment: When viewing the tranposed table in R, there are no issues. However, when using xtable to export the table to latex format, the values are unreconigzeable. Since the table was only 12 columns long, I just plotted it in latex manually the way I wanted it. Maybe there is something about the xtable package I'm unfamiliar with.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without a reproducible example, but I'll guess what you want to do. Try

```
t(as.matrix(your_data))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didnt help :( But thank you! I found a work around by manually creating the table in latex! :)